# case with date diff

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate or count number of rows that have a date diff of a certain amount but am not sure how

```
select count(case when date_diff('day', min_time, max_time) <= 7 then 1 else null end)  / count(*)
from table
```

but it doesn't seem to do the trick, not sure if there is a better way to implement this, thanks!

Comment: Integer division is probably the issue. Multiply the numerator by 1.00 before the division.

Comment: thanks, I try the * 1.0 and it still errored, do you think my code here is correct even with * 1.0? @shawnt00

Comment: You can't be using Postgres, as there is no `date_diff()` function in Postgres.  Which DBMS are you really using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: as @shawnt00 mentioned in a comment on the question, the problem is most likely the fact that you're dividing integers (resulting in an integer too, ie 0 or 1 in this case). Adding a `* 1.0` should fix the problem (or a cast to float8 if you prefer).

---

You can use the `FILTER` clause for this:

```
select count(*) filter (where date_diff('day', min_time, max_time) <= 7) * 1.0 / count(*)
from table
```

---

Though since it looks like you're computing an average maybe something like this would be the easiest:

```
select avg(case when date_diff('day', min_time, max_time) <= 7 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
from table
```

Comment: thanks, does this filter method work in postgres and mysql as well?

Comment: also, just for learning purposes if I wanted to use case instead of the filter, could it just be case( when date_diff...?

Comment: No, as far as I know mysql does not have `FILTER`. It is part of the SQL 2003 standard, but is optional. See [this](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter#compatibility) for more info.

Comment: @Chris90 the shawnt00 comment on your question should actually solve the problem

Comment: @Chris90: there's almost always a way to rewrite a `FILTER` with a `CASE WHEN`, and you're initial query should do the trick. The only instances where you really need `FILTER` is when there's no neutral element for the aggregate function. For instance, `ARRAY_AGG` will not ignore `null`, so there's no way to aggregate only a subset of the rows (except using `FILTER`). I have seen `FILTER` being quite a bit faster than `CASE WHEN`, though I don't have any example/link to show this.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this on SQL MODE and cant seem to figure out what sql engine they use so was erroring for me

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `count(*)`  with a where clause to select the rows?

Comment: bc thats not the only value in the select statement

Comment: Just include `count(*)` and the other fields in the select. Adding a `group by` when needed